# Store procedure doesn't return mutiple rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I just want to return multiple row using `CURSOR` of procedure. But It return empty value. I've used a simple select query for test purpose.

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_user`()
        READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE id INT;
        DECLARE name VARCHAR (256);

        DECLARE done int default 0;

        DECLARE curl CURSOR FOR

        SELECT id, name FROM user; 

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = 1;

        OPEN curl;
            data_loop:LOOP
                FETCH curl INTO id, name;
                IF done=1 THEN 
                    leave data_loop;
                END IF;
            END LOOP data_loop;
        CLOSE curl;
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A procedure must terminated (about multiple rows) with a SELECT.

But I can't show your final SELECT.

For example, you can use a temporary table USERS2 (`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE users2`) with the same fields of USER table. In the loop you can write in USERS2 (`INSERT INTO users2 ... and so on`), so at the end you'll write:

```
SELECT * FROM users2
```

Comment: Use of temporary table was an example. The important thing is returns a final SELECT